# how to set a breakpoint at the middle of a line of C# code?

Tags: c#, breakpoints

For example, I have the following code,

```
Variable.Method1().Method2();
```

I want to set the breakpoint after Method1() and before Method2(). Can I do so in visual studio?  How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Go to definition of `Method1` and set the breakpoint on the last line, *(I am not sure if there is other way)*

Comment: @jimmy set your breakspoints in your methods

Comment: you could always use the magical f11 key

Answer (score 6):

That won't work, but this will:

```
var result1 = Variable.Method1();
result1.Method2(); //set breakpoint here
```

Otherwise set a breakpoint at the first line of code on Method2 and then you can keep using that one line of code.

Comment: A very old answer, I know, but I'm curious what you mean by your last sentence, "Otherwise set a breakpoint at the first line of code on Method2 and then you can keep using that one line of code." It sounds like you are telling the OP to do exactly what he is asking *how* to do.

Comment: @PhatWrat I mean that he should place a breakpoint on the first line of code inside the body of the *Method2* method. That way, he can keep the one-liner call to both methods. Maybe that wasn't 100% clear in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you are debugging the program and the module with it's symbol have been loaded:

1. Go to Disassembly view of this particular line.
2. There should at least two `call` instructions. Figure out, which one is for Method1() or Method2(). It could be complicated.
3. Set breakpoint on any Disassembly line between them.

It can be more easy if have the program stopped within Method1() invocation. In that case:

1. Find the line in the call stack window of the function which have invoked Method1().
2. Set a breakpoint   by right click menu.
   By the way you can see different properties of breakpoints in the breakpoint window. In case of a breakpoint without 1 to 1 correspondence to the code line it's location would be something like

```
Fully.Qualified.Class.Method(Arg.Type) + 0x000000000000003e
```

Where 0x000000000000003e is offset.