# Setting a breakpoint in the middle of a line with multiple statements

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

I want to have a single line of code with an `if` and the result on the same line. Example

```
    if(_count > 0) return;
```

If I add a breakpoint on the line, it is set on the `if(_count > 0)`:

[image: Breakpoint on the if statement]

but what I want is to have the breakpoint on the `return;` like so:

[image: Breakpoint on return]

Is this doable?

NOTE: The closest question I could find on SO was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15942830/1467396) (which is not the same thing).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just click on a part of the line and press F9. This will set breakpoint in the middle of the line.

Comment: Um... Hitting `F9` always sets the breakpoint for the whole line in my case. What exactly do you mean by "click on a part of the line" then?

Comment: "Click on a part of the line" means place text cursor in that place. For me F9 sets the breakpoint for the current caret position in C# code, in C++ it sets the breakpoint for the whole line.

Comment: Right on--I just verified that this works in both 2015 and 2013.  @AnT--In other words, place the cursor on the statement that you want to break on.  In this case, put it on `return;` and then hit F9.

Comment: Works in VS2017

Comment: As Hucker pointed out a while ago that this works in VS2017, I just tested this in VS2022 and it still works as well.

Answer (score 3):

*EDIT*

mareko posted a 3rd option that seems to work just fine and is much easier than messing around with all this line-and-character stuff.  I'm going to leave this answer for completeness, but mareko's is much more practical in general.

---

Yes, but unfortunately, there is no drag-and-drop or anything like that.  You have 2 options:

**OPTION 1**

Move your return to a new line:

[image]

obviously, you can leave it like that, but if you want to keep the `return` on the same line as the `if`, you can simply delete the new line and the whitespace between the `if` and the `return` -- the breakpoint should "stick" to the `return` as you move it around.

This is probably the easier way to do it unless you are currently debugging code that does not have edit-and-continue for whatever reason. In that case, you'll need option 2...

---

**OPTION 2**

Alternately, you can place the cursor just before the r in 'return' and then look in your status bar to see which character ("Ch") you are on.  In my case, I'm on 20

[image]

now right click on the breakpoint and choose "Location..."

[image]

In the dialog box that pops up, set `Character:` to whatever the status bar was (20 in our example).

[image]

Comment: VS2015 redesigned this interafce. There's no longer a "Location" menu entry. And breakpoint's "Settings" dialog only allows editing the line number, but not the character.

Comment: Not true--the "Settings" dialog will let you set the character position; you just have to click on the link first.

Comment: In my VS2015 Update 3 I can only see a field for editing the line number. It could be the same difference mentioned in the comments under the other answer: it works in C#, but not in C or C++.